# Windows batch/script code to conditionally process based on date value in text file

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd

I am using Windows XP. The code can be used in a batch file or VBscript. I intend to use Windows scheduler to run the program.

I need code to read a date from a text file (could be the only line in the text file or the date could be included in the filename, I control the process that generates the file)
The code would then need to evaluate the text file date against the current date to confirm that the text file date is from the prior month.

I'm starting to build a process to be able to run 1st-of-the-month jobs once the monthly data has been refreshed. I'm new to building this kind of process using batch/script files.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You ask a very non-specific question with very little information. If the date is in a text file would the date be in the middle of any of the lines in the text file, or would it always be alone on a line? Would the date be preceded by anything like `DATE: `? What format would the date be in? `Fri 09/14/2012`? `09/14/2012`? `09/14/12`? `2012/09/14`? `12/09/14`? If the date is in the filename where would it be? The Front of the name? The middle? The end? Again, what format?

Comment: well, as I said, I control the process of creating the text file. So, with little experience in creating batch files, I wasn't sure how to create the date or where to put it, but it could be whatever makes the most sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling dates in `batch` is not impossible, but really, *really* ugly. I'd recommend using `VBScript` for this (or `PowerShell` if that's an option for you).

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f   = fso.GetFile("C:\PATH\TO\your_file_2012-07-23.txt")

fileDate  = CDate(Right(fso.GetBaseName(f.Name), 10))

If Month(DateAdd("m", 1, fileDate)) = Month(Now) Then
  WScript.Echo f.Name & " is from the previous month."
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

windows date command is very limited, you can try [realdate](http://www.huweb.hu/maques/realdate.htm)

```
realdate.com /f="DD" /s="set DAY=" >tmpdt.bat

call tmpdt.bat
if !%DAY%! == !%01%! (
echo not first day
exit 0
)
do your stuff here
```

Answer (score 1):

The advantage to this code is that you can just put the current date into `date.txt` like this:

```
echo %date%>date.txt
```

Then to act upon that date you only need the code following the line:

```
set lastmonth=
```

Code Follows:

```
@echo off
:Beginagain
set lastmonth= %date:~4,2%
set /a lastmonth=%lastmonth: 0=%-1
echo.
set /p lastmonth=Enter month for date.txt [1-12, Default = %lastmonth%, Q = Quit]: 
if %lastmonth%==Q goto :eof
if %lastmonth%==q goto :eof
set year=%date:~-4%
if %lastmonth% leq 0 (
  set lastmonth=12
  set /a year=year-1
)
if %lastmonth% lss 10 set lastmonth=0%lastmonth%
echo %date:~,4%%lastmonth%/%date:~7,2%/%year% > date.txt
set year=
set lastmonth=
set /p olddate=<date.txt
set olddate= %olddate:~4,2%
set olddate=%olddate: 0=%
set thismonth= %date:~4,2%
set thismonth=%thismonth: 0=%
set /a diff=thismonth-olddate
if %diff% lss 0 (
  echo Date from Last Year
) else if %diff%==0 (
  echo Date from this month
) else if %diff%==1 (
  echo Date from last month
) else if %diff% gtr 1 (
  echo Date from before last month
)
goto :Beginagain
```

The above code allows you to experiment with different months by looping until you choose to [Q]uit.

If you use the Default option, it will always output:

```
Date from last month
```

When run during the month of September, the above code will display:

```
Enter month for date.txt [1-12, Default = 8, Q = Quit]:
```

Where you can enter any month from 1 to 12 (any numbers above or below that act like a previous year), press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for the default month, or type <kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> to exit the program.

The default month will always be one month prior to whatever the current month is. So if the current month is January, the Default will be 12.  If the current month is December, the default is 11.